# Minimum value of trigonometry function

Tags: functions, trigonometry

How can I get the minimum value of function
$$f(x) = (2 + \sin x)(5 - \sin x)$$

I have used the differential ways but the answer was not match with the key answer.

By the way the key answer is $6$.

Comment: what did you do, what have you tried, what is the result you found? We could spot an issue with your reasonning, or a simple mistake when doing the computation...

Comment: By the way, take $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$, then you have $sin(\frac{5\pi}{2})=sin(\frac{\pi}{2})=1$ and thus $f(\frac{\pi}{2})=12$...

Comment: f(x) = 10-2 sin x + 5 sin x -sin x^2
     = -sinx^2 + 3 sin x + 10
then i use partial diffrential differential
with u = 3 u' = 0, v = sin x v'=cos x
u(x).v(x) = u'(x) v(x)+u(x)v'(x)
          = sin x + 3 cos x
and it is a mess, now i'm stucked

Comment: Look at what you wrote in your question, this is different than what you wrote in your comment... Is it $sin(5x)$ or $sin(x)$ in the first term?

Comment: i elaborate (2+sin5x)(5-sinx) and get that equation i post in the comment

Comment: No, by "elaborating" the equation you get $f(x)=10-2sin(x)+5sin(5x)-sin(x)sin(5x)$...

Comment: oh..sorry my fault. But how can i solve it with calculus ?

Comment: and yeah like you said it's sin x not sin 5x, so much mistake. Have edited it

Comment: @Martigan : could you write $\sin x$ or $\sin(x)$ instead of $sin(x)$.  Like this: \sin x.  That not only prevents italicization but also provides proper spacing in expressions like $a\sin b$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy You are right, and that's what I did in my answer. It was to emphasize the difference between the two expressions.

Comment: @Martigan : How does writing $sin(x)$ instead of $\sin(x)$ emphasize a difference between two expressions? ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so now the equation is:

$f(x)=(2+\sin x)(5-\sin x)=10+3\sin x -\sin^2 x$

$f'(x)=3\cos x-2\sin x \cos x=\cos x(3-2\sin x)$

Now $f'(x)=0$ for $\cos x=0$ of $\sin x=\frac 32$

Since $\sin x \leq 1$ you have only $\cos x=0$

$x=\frac{\pi}{2} +k \pi$, $k \in \mathbb{Z}$

You can finish from here easily.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the change of variable $t=\sin x$ and remember that $-1\le t\le 1$.

Then
$$(2+t)(5-t)=10+3t-t^2$$
has the derivative $3-2t$, which cancels at $t=\frac32$, out of the domain of $t$.

The minimum can only arise at one of the ends of that domain,
$$f(-1)=\color{green}6$$or $$f(1)=12.$$

No trigonometry !